# Error: constructor does not name a type

Tags: c++

So right now I have a pretty basic class cnt set up.  That is returning the error

> error: 'Cnt' does not name a type

for both cnt() and cnt(T t).  As far as I know, this is is line with how my textbook defines template classes, so what am I doing wrong here?

cnt.h:

```
#ifndef CNT_H_
#define CNT_H_

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>

class Cnt
{
public:
    Cnt();
    Cnt(T t);

private:
    T item;
    int cnt;
};

#include "cnt.cpp"
#endif
```

cnt.cpp:

```
template<typename T>
Cnt<T>::Cnt()
{
  cnt = 0;
}

template<typename T>
Cnt<T>::Cnt(T t)
{
  item = t;
  cnt = 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that should have been cnt, I've updated the post.

Comment: Your code [works](http://ideone.com/mQE7st). To the extent there is a problem, it must lie elsewhere, in the code you haven't shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In template metaprogramming your declaration and defination should be in same header file as,

```
#ifndef CNT_H_
#define CNT_H_

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>

class Cnt
{
public:
    Cnt();
    Cnt(T t);

private:
    T item;
    int cnt;
};

template<typename T>
Cnt<T>::Cnt()
{
  cnt = 0;
}

template<typename T>
Cnt<T>::Cnt(T t)
{
  item = t;
  cnt = 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to close the include guards with `#endif`.  And there is no reason to `#include <iostream>`

Comment: Metaprogramming is when you define things that don't do anything at runtime. This is just regular template programming.

Comment: Also this code should produce the same result as OP's given the `#include "cnt.cpp"` so I'm not sure what this does differently.

Comment: I have no idea how this was the  selected answer to this question. The `#include "cnt.cpp"` at the bottom of the header brings in the definition of the template in the same way that defining everything in the header here would. This just manually unrolls the preprocessor directive; it makes no sense how this would solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely instantiating your `Cnt` class without a template argument.  Instead of saying

```
Cnt c;
```

You need to provide a type, such as

```
Cnt<int> c;
```

---

Additionally you must define your functions inline, so instead of `cnt.h` and `cnt.cpp`, you should have one file `cnt.hpp` which contains:

```
#ifndef CNT_H_
#define CNT_H_

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Cnt
{
public:
    Cnt() : cnt(0) { }
    Cnt(T t) : item(t), cnt(0) { }

private:
    T item;
    int cnt;
};
#endif
```